# How to send raw data to Printer with Java Applet

Tags: html, printing, applet

Thanks in Advance.

I am new to Java Applet, i will tell my requirement and hope will get solution.

This is my Html Coding

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Print Via Applet</title></head>
<body>
<div id="text_to_print">
This is my Office<br />
This is my Office Address<br />
<center>Header of the Receipt</center><br />
1. Product 1          100.00<br />
2. Product 2          200.00<br />
                      ------<br />
TOTAL                 300.00<br />
                      ------<br />
Thanks for the Purchase.
</div>
<input type="button" value="Print Directly to the Dot Matrix by using Applet" />
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if anyone click the Button the contend inside the "text_to_print" div should print in the dot matrix printer directly without printer dialog.

One of my Friend told me that, this is possible if we use Applet. I search regard this on internet, but still I couldn't get the right solution for me need.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Once again thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/
Provides a a great interface to talk to the printer through javascript. Eventually the java applet does the job.